# Matching delimited string to table rows

Tags: sql, mysql, string

So I have two tables in this simplified example: People and Houses.  People can own multiple houses, so I have a People.Houses field which is a string with comma delimeters (eg: "House1, House2, House4").  Houses can have multiple people in them, so I have a Houses.People field, which works the same way ("Sam, Samantha, Daren").

I want to find all the rows in the People table corresponding to the the names of people in the given house, and vice versa for houses belong to people.  But I can't figure out how to do that.

This is as close as I've come up with so far:

```
   SELECT People.* 
     FROM Houses 
LEFT JOIN People ON Houses.People Like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', People.Name), '%')
    WHERE House.Name = 'SomeArbitraryHouseImInterestedIn'
```

But I get some false positives (eg: Sam and Samantha might both get grabbed when I just want Samantha.  And likewise with House3, House34, and House343, when I want House343).

I thought I might try and write a SplitString function so I could split a string (using a list of delimiters) into a set, and do some subquery on that set, but MySQL functions can't have tables as return values.

Likewise you can't store arrays as fields, and from what I gather the comma-delimited elements in a long string seems to be the usual way to approach this problem.

I can think of some different ways to get what I want but I'm wondering if there isn't a nice solution.

Comment: Are you able to modify the schema? If yes, do what RedFilter says.

Comment: ...and Daniel, and OMG, and Ramon...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Term Solution

For your immediate problem, the [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) is what you want to use for joining:

### For People

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM PEOPLE p
  JOIN HOUSES h ON FIND_IN_SET(p.name, h.people)
 WHERE h.name = ?
```

### For Houses

```
SELECT h.*
  FROM HOUSES h
  JOIN PEOPLE p ON FIND_IN_SET(h.name, p.houses)
 WHERE p.name = ?
```

### Long Term Solution

Is to properly model this by adding a table to link houses to people, because you're likely storing redundant relationships in both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE people_houses (
  house_id int,
  person_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (house_id, person_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (house_id) REFERENCES houses (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES people (id)
)
```

Comment: The short term solution worked just right!  Good for the immediate issue.  The long term solution you (and everyone else) shows I'm still not thinking properly about the schema...  It's a large-ish legacy database, but I have pretty good free reign to do what I want with it, so something I'll keep in mind as a project in the future.

Answer (score 6):

> Likewise you can't store arrays as fields, and from what I gather the comma-delimited elements in a long string seems to be the usual way to approach this problem.

I hope that's not true. Representing "arrays" in SQL databases shouldn't be in a comma-delimited format, but the problem can be correctly solved by using a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). Comma-separated fields should have no place in relational databases, and they actually violates the very [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

You'd want your table schema to look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
   id int NOT NULL,
   name varchar(50),
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE houses (
   id int NOT NULL,
   name varchar(50),
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE people_houses (
   house_id int,
   person_id int,
   PRIMARY KEY (house_id, person_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (house_id) REFERENCES houses (id),
   FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES people (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Then searching for people will be as easy as this:

```
SELECT  p.* 
FROM    houses h
JOIN    people_houses ph ON ph.house_id = h.id
JOIN    people p ON p.id = ph.person_id
WHERE   h.name = 'SomeArbitraryHouseImInterestedIn';
```

No more false positives, and they all lived happily ever after.

Answer (score 5):

The nice solution is to redesign your schema so that you have the following tables:

```
People
------
PeopleID (PK)
...


PeopleHouses
------------
PeopleID (PK) (FK to People)
HouseID (PK) (FK to Houses)


Houses
------
HouseID (PK)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to use another schema, like the one proposed by @RedFilter. You can see it as:

People table:
PeopleID
otherFields

Houses table:
HouseID
otherFields

Ownership table:
PeopleID
HouseID
otherFields

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just change the table name places, left side is People and then right side is Houses:

SELECT People.* 
     FROM People 
LEFT JOIN Houses ON Houses.People Like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', People.Name), '%')
    WHERE House.Name = 'SomeArbitraryHouseImInterestedIn'